# Accessing nested object in a union type

Tags: typescript

How to implement a function which takes an object(part of a union) with path and returns value of the `config` object for given path?

I'm trying the following:

```ts
type Foo = {
  config: {
    a: string;
  };
};

type Bar = {
  config: {
    b: string;
  };
};

type Baz = Foo | Bar;

const prop = <T extends Baz>(obj: T, path: keyof T["config"]) => {
  // I'm getting an error at this point:
  // "Type 'keyof T["config"] cannot be used to index type '{ a: string; } | { b: string }'
  return obj.config[path];
};
```

However, if I implement the similar function and trying to access fields at the root level(instead of the `config` object), it works smoothly:

```ts
type Foo = {
  a: string
}

type Bar = {
  b: string
}

type Baz = Foo | Bar

const prop = <T extends Baz>(obj: T, path: keyof T) => {
  return obj[path]
}
```

I'm assuming it has something with applying `keyof` on the object field of a Union type, but can not quite understand why.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly perfect, but this seems to accomplish what you are looking for in my testing:

```js
const prop = <T extends Baz, K extends keyof T['config']>(obj: T, path: K): T['config'][K] => {
    return (obj['config'] as T['config'])[path];
};
```

I tested by running this:

```js
const p = prop({ config: { b: 'hi' } }, 'b');
console.log(p);
```

Which output `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

You may rewrite your function as:

```ts
const prop = (obj: Baz, path: keyof Baz["config"]) => {
  return obj.config[path];
};
```

or:

```ts
const prop = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: { config: T }, path: K) => {
    return obj['config'][path];
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1858W)

As for the failure to index type with `keyof T["config"]`, it looks like that's a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36631#issuecomment-593650056).

Comment: Yeah, it seems a design limitation and there is no clear resolution of it..